# How do I make sure that two rows with the same number in the database are not chosen?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, logic

I am running a cronjob everyday for a rating site which runs a script that choose 3 random images from each category the visitors can then rate the images against each other like "Image 1 versus image 2 -> which one do you like the best", this works very well.

The problem is lets say that there are 2 of the same type of images

Let's assume

- id 1 is a ford mustang gt front view
- id 2 is a ford mustang gt front view just slightly different that id 1

This is a problem because if both id 1 and id 2 is chosen then its like saying two pretty identical images are versus each other? So I created a "separator column" where I give the images that represent the same the same number so in this simplified case id 1 and id 2 both have separator number 1 :)

Database structure

Table Cars

```
cars_id | cars_category | cars_source   | separator
--------+---------------+---------------+-----------
1       |    1          | 123.jpg       | 1
2       |    1          | 242.jpg       | 1
3       |    2          | 532.jpg       | 2
4       |    2          | 531.jpg       | 3
5       |    2          | 45fd.jpg      | 3
6       |    3          | da3.jpg       | 4
```

Current PHP script which choose 3 random images from each category

```
$cat1 = 1;
$cat2 = 2;
$cat3 = 3;
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" INSERT INTO daily_versus ( daily_versus_source, daily_versus_category) "
        . " (SELECT cars_source, cars_category "
        . " FROM cars "
        . " WHERE cars_category IN (?) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) "
        . " UNION "
        . " (SELECT cars_source, cars_category "
        . " FROM cars "
        . " WHERE cars_category IN (?) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) "
        . " UNION "
        . " (SELECT cars_source, cars_category "
        . " FROM cars "
        . " WHERE cars_category IN (?) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) ");
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $cat1, $cat2, $cat3);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Success VERSUS/INSERT";
} else {
    echo "Fail VERSUS/INSERT";
}
```

The above works as a charm, but what would be the smartest approach to integrate the separator numbers so two identical cars cannot be chosen... so basically if a car with the separator number "x" has been chosen the script can't chose another car with that same separator number?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to group each query by separator.

```
...
(SELECT cars_source, cars_category 
 FROM cars 
 WHERE cars_category IN (?) 
 GROUP BY SEPARATOR
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) 
...
```

mysql will take a "random" value from each group.
However it is not really random, for each separator group it will likely only take one (and always the same one) value whenever that separator is chosen.

Better
( -- to start  a comment / strip away before using)

```
...
(SELECT cars_source, cars_category 
 FROM 
 (select 
    (select id     -- one random id, for each of the 3 random separators
     from cars 
     where separator = ocars.separator -- will be a diff separator for each row in the outer query
     order by rand() limit 1
    ) as rand_id
  from cars as ocars 
  WHERE cars_category IN (?) 
  group by separator   -- each separator only once
  order by rand()      -- random separators
  limit 3              -- 3 random separators
) as cars_id
left join cars on cars.id = cars_id.rand_id   -- join the full row for each rand_id
) 
...
```

you should have indexes, on id, and on separator,
maybe also category

Comment: You mostly said it in your answer, but to be super clear for the tl;dr folks: the first code listing WILL NOT WORK.  MySql does the `group by` before the `order by rand`, so it generally (but not guaranteed) returns the same item for each of the distinct separators, then shuffles *those*.

I am curious as to why you and OP both favored `cars_category IN (?)` over `cars_category = (?)` though...

Comment: the first "group by" will work in special cases. e.g. if the physical order in the table changed. But yes the "order by" only affects the "separator", and not the item within a group of the same "separator".
About the "in ()", I just copied it.

Comment: This looks a bit confusing at first glance, i will try to analyse it through and see if this is what i am looking for :)

Comment: where did rand_id come from :) ?

Comment: rand_id is the result of the innermost subquery.
The "limit 3" subquery, chooses 3 distinct "separator" values. For each of them, one (limit 1) random "cars.id" is chosen (if the separator, has more than one row). This "cars.id" is returned by the subquery, and named rand_id.
-
The query assumes that separators are not re-used by other categories. That is all items with the same separator, are always in the same category.
So if the innermost query does "separator = ocars.separator" this will return rows matching the category chosen by the next outer query.

Answer (score -1):

Rank by [seperator] and select the top one.

Comment: This does not have any relation to what i asked